Word macro - I want the macro to go up one level then search subfolders for a document
Word macro - I want the macro in my Word doc to go up one level then search subfolders for a specific document. So currently the macro works fine dragging data from another Word document when the document is in the same folder using the Dir command.
Now the Word document I want the data from has been moved to another folder, I am struggling to get the macro to recursive search for it.
The folder in which it sits will be named differently so I was using wildcards, etc.
Any thoughts?
I know the macro works because when I run it as it used to be it works fine but the issue is searching subfolders one level up.
    Dim ThisMPERFile As Word.Document
    Dim filePath As String
   
    Set ThisMPERFile = ActiveDocument
    filePath = ThisMPERFile.Path
    
    logName = Dir(filePath & "\*_doc.docm")


Not a VBA thing, but: .. is a wildcard to go up a folder level, exactly as you want: i.e. If you start from C:\Temp\Example\New Folder, and instead you navigate to C:\Temp\Example\New Folder\.., then it will be the same as C:\Temp\Example.  So, C:\Temp\Example\New Folder\..\*.csv will be the same as C:\Temp\Example\*.csv

Thanks for the reply, I had tried that a while ago but it didn't want to play when I was assigning the path and filename as a string, I don't know why.

From what I am reading Dir doesn't do recursive unless you loop it? I am very new to VBA so don't know any better!

I did manage to isolate the previous folder level by using the ‘left’ command which gave me the bit I wanted but failed searching the sub folders of that level. But I am seeing some nice code around which I could alter to search for my purposes.

In vba, you can use the FileSystemObject object, you can reference it in the object browser.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filesystemobject-object
In this object, there is a GetParentFolderName method that returns the parent folder of a folder.
This link explains how to reference it in VBA, although in the article it says vb6, it is possible to use it in VBA:
This doc is on portuguese of Brazil.
https://www.macoratti.net/filesyst.htm
